# Capybara find nested CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, css-selectors, capybara, integration-testing

Initial approach was to try this:

```
page.should have_xpath('//input[@data-name="Sleeping bag"][@data-number="1"][@value="This first tent should have a rainfly"]')
```

It refuses to work, so I would like to try a CSS selector but not sure how to select. There are multiple input items with a `data-name="Sleeping bag"`, but only one will have a `data-number="1"`. I.e, the rendered HTML looks like:

```
<div class="form-group" id="cart">
  <ul class="cart">
    <li class="cart-item" data-id="3" data-name="Sleeping bag" data-number="1">&nbsp;Sleeping bag&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
      <input data-id="3" data-number="1" data-name="Sleeping bag" class="specifications-field" id="specification" name="items[][specification]" placeholder="Optional specifications" type="text">
    <li class="cart-item" data-id="3" data-name="Sleeping bag" data-number="2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign minus-icon" id="remove_item" data-id="3" data-name="Sleeping bag" data-number="2">&nbsp;Sleeping bag&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>      
      <input data-id="3" data-number="2" data-name="Sleeping bag" class="specifications-field" id="specification" name="items[][specification]" placeholder="Optional specifications" type="text">
  </ul>
</div>
```

How do I find the first one and check it's value? Something that is in this format:

```
find_field('pickupaddress').value.should eq "test"
```

Also open to different approaches! Was actually thinking of executing script if it came down to because jQuery can find the field like this `$('[id=specification][data-number=1]')`

Comment: Code you post more of your page source? First thought: page.has_css?('selector') the get the element. I can give you better code with more of your page source around your selection

Comment: Your inputs dont have a value attribute. So are you trying to get the value that is entered on the input?

Comment: find('input[data-id="1"]') - will return element. Adding '.text' to end of call will get value. You could get more creative with grabbing the parent to the li and creating an openstruct and using that to loop through it. I also suggest trying in dev tools chrome perhaps on console tab $('input[data-id="1"]') and see if devtools returns the element.   Is this a live site i could look at?

Comment: That test passes regardless of what `text` I give it...